# ASP NET Core service with Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup some of my ASP NET Core services with a Nginx Reverse Proxy but I've been stuck with the same problem for some time now: **Getting my service to use the original path for redirects.**

I have a service called ConfigCloud, that should be accessed via **site.net/api/configcloud**. Accessing the service works fine but whenever my service performs a redirect or sends a Url to another service, it never includes the **/api/configcloud** prefix and this prevents the service from being usable.

This has been quite a headache when it comes to authentication and authorisation as those processes involve redirects and call-backs. For example, **site.net/api/configcloud/account/profile** will redirect the user to **site.net/account/login**, which is not desirable. Also, when my Auth provider (Auth0) wants to send a callback, it will send back **site.net/callback** instead of **site.net/api/configcloud/callback**.

I have attempted many different Kestrel and Nginx configurations to get this working, including those suggested by Microsoft ([Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu), [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-8.0)).

It's difficult for me to determine whether the problem lies with my Kestrel config or Nginx config.

Initially, I would have thought would have been the answer to this problem but that doesn't seem have any effect.

Environment:

- ASP NET Core 7
- Nginx latest
- Docker Compose via WSL 2

Current Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    server_name localhost site.net;
    
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.net/privkey.pem;
        
    # Increase client upload size.
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    
    # Reuse ssl sessions, avoids unnecessary handshakes.
    ssl_session_tickets on;

    location /api/configcloud/ {
        proxy_pass          https://aurora-configcloud/;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_set_header    Referer $http_referer;

        # I'm sure some of these are unnecessary but I've just been trying everything.
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-Port $remote_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host:$remote_port;
    }

    # Other services
```

I would appreciate any assistance on this matter as it has become quite a blocker in trying to learn backend web dev. Thank you.

**Edit:**
I have found a working solution. The following code had to be added to my ASP.NET Core program.

```cs
  app.Use((httpContext, next) =>
  {
      httpContext.Request.PathBase = pathBase;
      return next();
  });
```

The above code works as you expect a Base URL to work in other environments, unlike [ASP NET Core's UsePathBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: `It's difficult for me to determine whether the problem lies with my Kestrel config or Nginx config` then do basic debugging by removing one of those components from the equation to isolate which one is causing the problem. Stack Overflow does not exist to do that debugging for you.

Comment: If I remove one of those components then how should I test whether reverse proxy redirects work? It works completely fine when there is no base path coming from a proxy. I have done similar setups with Nginx and non-ASP NET Core environments, which work fine so it leads to me think there is a specific setup required to get this working but I cannot find any advice about this.
The only related advice I have found is using Nginx Ingress Controller with K8S but I don't want to migrate to something so complex for something that is usually easily solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution. The following code had to be added to the ASP.NET Core program.

```cs
  app.Use((httpContext, next) =>
  {
      httpContext.Request.PathBase = pathBase;
      return next();
  });
```